# Overriding setter on object

Tags: javascript

I have an `Object` with a getter and setter where I'm intending to protect a property so that it can only be updated through a method.  Let's call this object `Person` which has the following structure:

```
function Person(data) {
    var _name = data.name;

    this.name = function () {
        return _name;
    };
    this.setName = data.setName || function (newValue) {
        _name = newValue;
    };
}
```

I want to be able to override `setName` and pass different implementations to each instance of `Person` but I can't quite seem to get it to work.  I'm certain this is a closure issue, but I just can't get my head around it.

Given the following usage scenario, what am I doing wrong?

```
var p1 = new Person({
    name: "Paul",
    setName: function (newValue) {
        this._name = newValue;
    }
});
var p2 = new Person({ name: "Bob" });
p1.setName("Paul (updated)");
p2.setName("Bob (updated)");
```

`p1` never updates its value and so is always "Paul" whereas `p2` does and becomes "Bob (updated)".  I want to be able to create as many unique instances of `Person` as I want, where **some** of them have their own implementation of `setName` and others will just use the default instance.

I've tried wrapping `data.setName` up in a closure like this and setting my custom `setName` to return the value instead:

```
this.setName = data.setName ? function () {
    return (function (value) {
        value = data.setName();
    }(_name));
} : function (newValue) { _name = newValue; }
```

But I'm having no luck - I obviously just don't get closures as well as I thought!  Any and all help always appreciated.

## codepen.io [example here](http://codepen.io/pcaldredbann/pen/dCsgB?editors=001)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> this._name = newValue;
> ```

`_name` is a private variable, not a property. It cannot be accessed on `this`. Have a look at [Javascript: Do I need to put this.var for every variable in an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13418669/1048572) if you're not sure about the difference.

> ```
> function (value) {
>     value = data.setName();
> }
> ```

`value` here is a local variable to that function's scope, not a "reference" to the `_name` variable you passed in. Setting it will only put a different value in that local variable, but not change anything else.

---

Possible solutions:

- Pass a setter function that has access to the `_name` variable to the
  validator:

  ```
  function Person(data) {
      var _name = data.name;

      this.name = function () {
          return _name;
      };
      if (data.nameValidator) 
          this.setName = function(newValue) {
              _name = data.nameValidator(newValue, _name);
          };
      else
          this.setName = function (newValue) {
              _name = newValue;
          };
  }
  var p1 = new Person({
      name: "Paul",
      nameValidator: function (newValue, oldValue) {
          return (newValue /* ... */) ? newValue : oldValue;
      }
  });
  ```
- Or let the validator return the value:

  ```
  function Person(data) {
      var _name = data.name;

      this.name = function () {
          return _name;
      };
      this.setName = function (newValue) {
          _name = newValue;
      };
      if (data.makeNameValidator) 
          this.setName = data.makeNameValidator(this.setName);
  }
  var p1 = new Person({
      name: "Paul",
      makeNameValidator: function (nameSetter) {
          return function(newValue) {
              if (newValue) // ...
                  nameSetter(newValue);
          };
      }
  });
  ```
- Or make `_name` a property to which the validator can write. You could also put this on the original `data` object, for not exposing it on the `Person` interface:

  ```
  function Person(data) {
      this.name = function () {
          return data.name;
      };
      if (data.setName)
          this.setName = data.setName.bind(data);
      else
          this.setName = function(newValue) {
              _name = newValue;
          };
  }
  var p1 = new Person({
      name: "Paul",
      setName: function (newValue) {
          if (newValue) // ...
              this.name = newValue;
      }
  });
  ```

Comment: I see now that I was hugely over-complicating my design (in my head!), this is now working and I've updated the codepen, thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't say any of my designs are not complicated :-)

Comment: Haha very true, although what I meant was in my head I imagined replacing the entire method signature - parameters, return types the works, all within a closure... and then it hit, I was thinking WAY outside the box.

Answer (score 2):

I feel this is the simplest solution so far, using `bind`:

```
function Person(data) {
    var _data = {name:data.name};

    this.name = function () {
        return _data.name;
    };
    this.setName = data.setName ? data.setName.bind(_data) : function (newValue) {
        _data.name = newValue;
    };
}

var p1 = new Person({
  name: "Paul",
  setName: function (newName) {
      this.name = newName;
  }
});
var p2 = new Person({ name: "Bob" });
p1.setName("Paul (updated)");
p2.setName("Bob (updated)");

console.log(p1.name());
console.log(p2.name());
```

Instead of using a primitive to store the name we use an object, whose reference we can pass as `this` using `bind`. Originally, when you wrote `this._name = newValue;`, `this` meant something quite different from what you thought, namely the object you pass the intantiate the `new Person`.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T23ak/1/)

Comment: @PaulAldred-Bann Although you've accepted an answer, I encourage you to look at this, I think it's elegant and quite close to what you had in mind in the first place, and uses, in my opinion, a very basic core feature of JavaScript effectively.

Comment: @Mosho I missed this one! I like how the private variable has been changed to an object and passed as scope to the custom method.  However, in practice (the real application) I need to pass the `Person` as scope in cases where I `$.extend` the value passed via the params. Hence, I'm calling @Bergi's solution using `.bind`.

Answer (score 0):

U think it's a problem with `this`

```
this.setName = function (newValue) {
  if (data.setName) {
    data.setName.call(this, newValue);
  } else {
    _name = newValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: So did I, but unfortunately this doesn't work.  I've updated the codepen with this however.

Comment: Sorry, _name is not accessed via `this` so this is no solution. Its a clusore problem, because only function defined within the scope of `Person` have access to `_name`.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `this._name` in your `p1` Person, whereas you are accessing the 'internal' variable `_name` in your `Person()` function, instead of `this._name`. This can easily be fixed by adding `this.` to parts in your `Person()` class.

```
function Person(data) {
    this._name = data.name;

    this.name = function () {
        return this._name;
    };
    this.setName = data.setName || function (newValue) {
        this._name = newValue;
    };
}
```

Your second example, with the wrapping, is not working due to some errors you appear to have made in the `setName()` function. Firstly, you are not passing anything to the `data.setName()` function, meaning that it is receiving `undefined` for the first parameter. Next up, you are setting `value` *to* the returned value, whereas you should instead be setting `_name` to the returned value. Try this instead:

```
this.setName = data.setName ? function (newValue) {
    return (function (value) {
        _name = data.setName();
    }(newValue));
} : function (newValue) { _name = newValue; }
```

Comment: Exposing `_name` is what I'm trying to avoid - I'm aware my current design may not be suitable for what I'm trying to achieve - but that's why I'm here :o)

Comment: Try using your second idea with the second example I provided, it should work then ;)